# Channels' connection status

Tags: mirth

I am not able to get channel live connection status ie.(idle, receiving, connected). I got channel statistics using "ChannelUtil" class but I have no idea how to get live connection status of channel. I am using mirth connect version 3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Client API.

```
GET /extensions/dashboardstatus/channelStates/{channelId}
```

Comment: Mirth versions 3.4 and higher expose a REST api, also referred to as the Client API. There is self-hosted documentation if you click on the Client API link while logged in to the Administrator client. You can also visit in your browser https://yourmirthhost:8443/api, assuming you haven't changed the default port. There is additional information in the official User Guide, which can be downloaded from https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/NextGen-Connect-Integration-Engine-Downloads

The REST path in my answer is under the Extension Services section of the online documentation.